# Enable javaFx in netbeans in ubuntu

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

I have installed netbeans 8.2 on ubuntu. But when I try to create a new JavaFx application, I get the following error:

[image]

How do I resolve this issue ? I have jdk 8 installed. Please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: You're on Linux, which makes me assume you're using an OpenJDK distribution. As I understand it, OpenJDK never included the JavaFX libraries on Linux (could be wrong). Follow the directions in the error message: Install JavaFX and then configure NetBeans to point to said installation.

Comment: yes, using open jdk 1.8. Didn't find JavaFx sdk for linux either.

Comment: Might help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091157/javafx-missing-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Thanks, followed that step as well, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you "_go to Platform Manager, create a non-default Java SE platform, then go to the JavaFX tab, enable JavaFX and fill in the paths to valid JavaFX SDK and JavaFX Runtime_"?

Comment: I can't see the JavaFX tab in there. What's wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199476/discussion-between-ashy-ashcsi-and-slaw).